# Stop accordion expanding on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am useless with JS as I have no idea what Im doing but I've hit a wall that CSS wont get me past.

I have a page on a website where there are some accordion text sections. The problem I am having is that I want to make it so that none of these are expanded on page load, I want them to all be hidden. Currently the page opens with the top option expanded.

Below is what I believe to be the responsible script, can anyone shed any light for me?

Thanks in advance.

```
/**
* Accordion-folding functionality.
*
* Markup with the appropriate classes will be automatically hidden,
* with one section opening at a time when its title is clicked.
* Use the following markup structure for accordion behavior:
*
* <div class="accordion-container">
*   <div class="accordion-section open">
*       <h3 class="accordion-section-title"></h3>
*       <div class="accordion-section-content">
*       </div>
*   </div>
*   <div class="accordion-section">
*       <h3 class="accordion-section-title"></h3>
*       <div class="accordion-section-content">
*       </div>
*   </div>
*   <div class="accordion-section">
*       <h3 class="accordion-section-title"></h3>
*       <div class="accordion-section-content">
*       </div>
*   </div>
* </div>
*
* Note that any appropriate tags may be used, as long as the above classes are present.
*
* @since 3.6.0.
*/

( function( $ ){

$( document ).ready( function () {

    // Expand/Collapse accordion sections on click.
    $( '.accordion-container' ).on( 'click keydown', '.accordion-section-title', function( e ) {
        if ( e.type === 'keydown' && 13 !== e.which ) { // "return" key
            return;
        }

        e.preventDefault(); // Keep this AFTER the key filter above

        accordionSwitch( $( this ) );
    });

});

/**
 * Close the current accordion section and open a new one.
 *
 * @param {Object} el Title element of the accordion section to toggle.
 * @since 3.6.0
 */
function accordionSwitch ( el ) {


    var section = el.closest( '.accordion-section' ),
        sectionToggleControl = section.find( '[aria-expanded]' ).first(),
        container = section.closest( '.accordion-container' ),
        siblings = container.find( '.open' ),
        siblingsToggleControl = siblings.find( '[aria-expanded]' ).first(),
        content = section.find( '.accordion-section-content' );

    // This section has no content and cannot be expanded.
    if ( section.hasClass( 'cannot-expand' ) ) {
        return;
    }





    // Add a class to the container to let us know something is happening inside.
    // This helps in cases such as hiding a scrollbar while animations are executing.
    container.addClass( 'opening' );

    if ( section.hasClass( 'open' ) ) {
        section.toggleClass( 'open' );
        content.toggle( true ).slideToggle( 150 );
    } else {
        siblingsToggleControl.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        siblings.removeClass( 'open' );
        siblings.find( '.accordion-section-content' ).show().slideUp( 150 );
        content.toggle( false ).slideToggle( 150 );
        section.toggleClass( 'open' );
    }

    // We have to wait for the animations to finish
    setTimeout(function(){
        container.removeClass( 'opening' );
    }, 150);

    // If there's an element with an aria-expanded attribute, assume it's a toggle control and toggle the aria-expanded value.
    if ( sectionToggleControl ) {
        sectionToggleControl.attr( 'aria-expanded', String( sectionToggleControl.attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ) );
    }
}
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: You might not need javascript: http://www.mraffaele.com/labs/css-only-accordions/

Comment: Remove the open class on the first accordion.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I am using a wordpress plugin so wanted to ideally do it with this.

Comment: Will, have you read [ask]? In its current form, your question looks like you are here because you are (quoting you) *"useless with js"*. And you need a job done, using js. That's a loose definition of any client looking for free work and, therefore, your question is off-topic here. Consider asking questions if you are trying to learn some concepts and hit a wall, **after going through documentation**, pointing to the parts of documentation that are unclear to you. We're here to help others advance/learn, not to work for free. I do hope you understand and find my comment helpful.

Comment: Btw, if your theme has a place where you can add js, placing this in there will most likely solve your issue: `!function(o){o(window).load(function(){o(".accordion-section").removeClass("open")})}(jQuery);`. You can also wrap it inside a `<script type="text/javascript"> the above code here </script>` and place it in your page's content. It should work.

Comment: Thanks, sorry - I didnt realise the conotations of my question. I am building the site myself and it was something I was stuck on but take your comment on board.

Comment: I tried adding this into the head but unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: Add it at the end of the scripts you placed above. If it doesn't work it's either because some other code re-opens the accordion after the above script runs or you're adding it too soon and jQuery is not loaded yet in the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the exact same HTML as in the top of the file, remove the `open` class from the first accordion:

```
<div class="accordion-container">
    <!-- The next accordion-section also had the open class -->
    <div class="accordion-section">
        <h3 class="accordion-section-title"></h3>
        <div class="accordion-section-content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-section">
        <h3 class="accordion-section-title"></h3>
        <div class="accordion-section-content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-section">
        <h3 class="accordion-section-title"></h3>
        <div class="accordion-section-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a worspress plugin so I am not generating the html so not sure how I could change this in the page?

Comment: Aren't there any plugin options? And what files can you edit?

Comment: No, I have full access to all js files and the php etc but cant figure out where I could change that.